# classes.dex file size vs. APK Analyzer size(s)

Tags: android

I want to approximate an Android lib's size by adding it as a dependency in a demo app and then analyzing it with Android Studio's APK Analyzer. The thing is, the APK Analyzer is extremely unclear about *classes.dex* file sizes. I have the following information:

1. **Raw File Size** and **Download Size** from APK Analyzer's file listing, right when you open an APK.
2. A **Size** column (unspecified whether it is Raw or Download size) for all packages included in *classes.dex* after double clicking the file mentioned in item 1. The sum of all sizes in this column amounts to about twice the size in item 1.
3. If I unpack the APK, the unpacked *classes.dex* **file size** is about 1.5 times bigger than the one in item 2.

So, which one is the real *classes.dex* size? Which one do I take for the (approximate) size my lib will take up after an app containing it is installed on a device?

Comment: You found any tool to see the real size @felipe-gonçalves ?

Comment: Nope. Ended up with a very rough based on these values, since they probably mean different things (before/after installation, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
unzip -p my.apk classes.dex | wc -c
```

in Linux to get the file size. If the APK has two or more `classes.dex`, then you can `unzip -l` and then `grep classes.dex` to get the sizes.

In a device installation, the `classes.dex`'s size shouldn't change. If your device runs a version of Android with ART, then it will compile the APK at installation.